# how to upload configurations using freecwmp

Tags: soap, protocols

Hi I am using freecwmp as a TR069 client. I found the source code and steps from freecwmp.org.
I have tested the code with openacs for the following features : downlaod, get/set parameters, reset in freecwmp. Our task also requires the tr069 client to ask the acs(auto configuration server) to upload a file from client to server. any ideas on how that can be done ?
If there are any doubts regarding the question please comment and I will explain in detail.

Comment: This is done, I have added the upload feature in freecwmp :)

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this on the freecwmp mailing list or the IRC channel. This feature is not yet supported but it will be easy to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find an answer using freecwmp?

If not, you can do it using [OpenACS](https://sourceforge.net/p/openacs/) with this line of javascript:

```js
result = cpe.Upload(cmd_key, file_type, acs_url, user, pwd, delay_seconds)
```